# parse - Load NSUInteger from User Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I play around with *parse.com*

For my little project I wanna download an Integer from Parse User Class (_User) in to a `float`.

How would I do that?

I tried with that code:

```
 PFQuery *updatingQuery = [PFUser query];
[updatingQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:objectID];
[updatingQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * updating, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {
         myFloat = [EXPData valueForKey:@"Data"];

     }

 }];
```

But I will become an error:

*Assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'id'*

How can I retrieve a float?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you need !

Answer (score 0):

Basically do the opposite of uploading after you retrieve the object:

```
 PFQuery *updatingQuery = [PFUser query];
 [updatingQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:objectID];
 [updatingQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
     int someNumber = object[@"IntegerClass"];
     self.someLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", someNumber];
    }

 }];
```

Please read through Parse docs before asking something fundamental, or show that you've exercised some research. This is a fundamental basic of Parse query:

Here are some key sites you should bookmark if you plan on being a Parse developer:

- https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/
- https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications
- https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide
- https://parse.com/docs/downloads

Comment: Thanks, but even I load the objects in to a NSUInteger i will become an error like: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') from 'id __nullable'

Comment: where are you getting EXPData from? and you will need to revise your question to more clearly state your end goal. It's a little confusing now that you've altered it from the original post

Comment: I get the object from Parse User class from the column "Number" (Integer Column)